# How to submit a lightning:recordEditForm from a button that isn't nested?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

The [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm_) documentation provides this example:

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

where a a click on the nested submit button causes the data to be saved.

Anyone know of a reliable/documented way to get the `lightning:recordEditForm` to save based on a click of a button located elsewhere in the page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can manually trigger the submit action of `lightning:recordEditForm` component without having to use `<lightning:button type="button"/>` which can be found in the new component documentation UI : `https://<myDomain>/componentReference/suite.app`

[image]

Sample code:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="0032800001DYoc0" objectApiName="Contact">
      <lightning:messages />
      <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
      <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
      <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
<lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="button" name="update" label="update" onclick="{!c.update}" />
```

controller:

```
update : function(component,event,helper) {
   component.find("editForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: While this works for submitting the form, I did notice that using this approach does not fire the `onsubmit` handler of the form if you have one set.

Answer (score 4):

This is working as designed. onsubmit belongs to the form (or more specifically the button in the form).

The assumption is, if you are already outside of the form, i.e. you know that another button/link is going to submit the form, you can just do whatever processing you need before firing the submit method.

Answer (score 1):

This bypasses the validation rules and built in messages. Is there a way to keep them?
It seems strange that an action button dispalys a modal dialog but the button has to be in the body rather than the footer.